# Subset of A Regular Language

Tags: automata, regular-language

I need to show that a subset of a regular language is regular or not. I think it may not be regular but I could not find a counter example.

Do you have any simple example to prove that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you asking whether every subset of every regular language is regular? The answer to that is *no*. If you’re asking about a particular subset of a particular language, then we’ll need to know the particulars.

Comment: I think it may not be regular but I need t prove that so I need a counter example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $N$ be some non-regular language over some alphabet $\Sigma$.  You should know several examples of non-regular languages.

Then $$N\subset \Sigma^\ast$$

and $\Sigma^\ast$ is regular.

Answer (score 1):

Let $L_1 = \{ a^mb^n \}_{m,n,}$, $L_2 = \{ a^nb^n \}_n$. $L_2 \subset L_1$.

$L_1$ is regular, $L_2$ is not..

Comment: Why so complicated? Just let $L_1=\{a,b\}^*$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: I wanted the similarity to be obvious.

Comment: I suspected as much, but I don’t see the point.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Nothing deep, just highlighting the 'sensitivity' of the language to its description.